# Skinning Drools Guvnor

Tags: jboss, drools, skinning

I am fairly new to Jboss 5.1 and Guvnor 5.3 and have been trying to figure out how to change the look and feel of Guvnor. I haven't been able to find a solution and may be missing something. I realize you can edit the CSS file, but I'm looking for a way to edit it while seeing what I'm doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to edit the CSS-file then I would use FireBug in Firefox or Chromes dev tools to see my changes immediately and then copy the changes to the CSS-file. I should warn you that it is not possible to edit everything using the CSS.

For bigger changes you need to clone the source codes and compile your own war [1]. Some experience in GWT and java will not hurt here. I recommend using one of the tags in the Guvnor GitHub repository as your base. The master can be unstable. Check the README [2] for how to set up the project in your IDE. To build the war you need to run "mvn -Dfull clean install" the wars will be in the guvnor-distribution-wars -folder.

[1] https://github.com/droolsjbpm/guvnor
[2] https://github.com/droolsjbpm/droolsjbpm-build-bootstrap/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Thanks for the instruction. I'm using Netbeans and I'm wondering if there were any special instructions for getting Guvnor to work with that program rather than Eclipse?

Comment: Nope, sorry. At the moment the README only covers Eclipse and IDEA.

Comment: Ok, Thanks. After some trial and error, I have GWT development mode up and running. Now to look through the files and figure out what to edit. :)